# How Do I Add Multiple Directories And Filter Patterns To A SourceSet?

Tags: gradle

Due to historical reasons I have resources in multiple directories.

If I needed everything in these directories I could just modify the source set like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir = 'src/main/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir = 'src/main/resources'
            srcDir = 'resources'
            srcDir = 'properties'
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have different include/exclude filters that I need to apply for each directory and they unfortunately conflict each other and any include/exclude filter in the `resources` it applies it to all 3 of the directories.

How can I filter each directory individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SourceDirectorySet`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html) (the class of `sourceSets.main.resource`) provides a method [`source(SourceDirectorySet)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html#source-org.gradle.api.file.SourceDirectorySet-) that allows adding other source sets. New instances of `SourceDirectorySet` may be created using [`ObjectFactory.sourceDirectorySet(String, String)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/model/ObjectFactory.html#sourceDirectorySet-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), so you could try something like the following:

```
def resourcesSet = objects.sourceDirectorySet("resources", "Resources")
resourcesSet.srcDir 'resources'
// apply filter to resourcesSet

def propertiesSet = objects.sourceDirectorySet("properties", "Properties")
propertiesSet.srcDir 'properties'
// apply filter to propertiesSet

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            source(resourcesSet)
            source(propertiesSet)
        }
    }
}
```